# how to randomly multiply symbolic array with matrix

Tags: matlab

Assuming a matrix W of dimensions `n-by-n` which is known, and its elements are positive numbers between `0` and `1`.
Assuming also a symbolic vector

```
k = [a b c d];
```

I need to randomly multiply each all the non-zero component of `W` with one at a time of the components of `k`(randomly), such as e.g.:

[image: this one for example]

What I tried:

```
k = sym('a', [1 4]);
msize = numel(k);
k(randperm(msize, 1))

for i = 1:length(W)
    for j = 1:length(W)
        W(i,j) = W(i,j)*(k);
    end
end
```

and the error was the following:

```
The following error occurred converting from sym to double:
Error using maplemex
Error, (in MTM:-double) cannot handle unevaluated name `a1` in evalhf
```

Comment: Where have you gotten stuck? On generating the random possibilities? Selecting the nonzero elements of `W`? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried the following, but it was not successful:

`k = sym('a', [1 4]);`

`msize = numel(k);`

`k(randperm(msize, 1));`

`A*(k)`

Comment: i was hoping, within a loop from 1 to length(A), that this way I could manage to make a different value of k each time, to multiply with another A component

Comment: Please add all clarifications to the question itself using [edit]. What do you mean by "not successful"? Did it give you an error? Did it blow up your car?

Comment: How are `W` and `A` defined in your code? Please see [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we define the inputs:

```
% PARAMETERS

% k: symbolic vector of length m
m = 4;
k = sym('a', [1, m]);

% W: n-by-n matrix of doubles
n = 5;
W = rand(n);
```

Here is the calculation:

```
% CALCULATION

% random assignment of elements of k to the shape of W
I = randi(m, n);
K = k(I);

% result: element-wise multiplication of K and W
result = K .* W;
```

Comment: Why not just use `randi` to generate integers in the range `[1,m]` instead of scaling floats?